# What is the best way to do complicated string search on 5M records ? Application layer or DB layer?

Tags: javascript, csv, io, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I have a use case where I need to do complicated string matching on records of which there are about 5.1 Million of. When I say complicated string matching, I mean using library to do fuzzy string matching. (http://blog.bripkens.de/fuzzy.js/demo/)

The database we use at work is SAP Hana which is excellent for retrieving and querying because it's in memory so I would like to avoid pulling data out of there and re-populating it in memory on the application layer but at the same time I cannot take advantages of the libraries (there is an API for fuzzy matching in the DB but it's not comprehensive enough for us).

What is the middle ground here? If I do pre-processing and associate words in the DB with certain keywords the user might search for I can cut down the overhead but are there any best practises that are employed when It comes to this ?

If it matters. The list is a list of Billing Descriptors (that show up on CC statements) therefore, the user will search these descriptors to find out which companies the descriptor belongs too.

Comment: Seems like you're getting the right idea with pre-processing.  I was about to suggest leveraging SAP's abilities to narrow results before using more capable libraries in the application: a middle ground of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "billing descriptor" is a single column, probably of type (N)VARCHAR I would start with a very simple SAP HANA fuzzy search, e.g.:

```
SELECT top 100 SCORE() AS score, <more fields>
FROM <billing_documents>
WHERE CONTAINS(<bill_descr_col>, <user_input>, FUZZY(0.7))
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Maybe this is already good enough when you want to apply your js library on the result set. If not, I would start to experiment with the similarCalculationMode option, like  'similarcalculationmode=substringsearch' etc. And I would always have a look at the response times, they can be higher when using some of the options.
Only if response times are to high, or many active concurrent users are using your query, I would try to create a fuzzy search index on your search column. If you need more search options, you can also create a fullext index.

But that all really depends on you use case, the values you want to compare etc.
There is a very comprehensive set of features and options for different use cases, check help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Search_Developer_Guide_en.pdf.

In a project we did a free style search on several address columns (name, surname, company name, post code, street) and we got response times of 100-200ms on ca 6 Mio records WITHOUT using any special indexes.